# Menu bar on web pages not visible in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, menu-bar, facebook

I am facing this problem when ever I am visiting any website that has go a Menubar on the top, then the part remains half invisible in Safari.

See below:

**Here is screenshot of SoF site on Safari:**

[image]

**Facebook pages:**

[image]

**and Quora:** 
[image]

**Anyone else faced similar problems?
Any resolution to this?**

OS: Yosemite Version 10.10.2

Browser: Safari Version 8.0.3

Comment: so your scrolling is stuck ?

Comment: Basically not! Those were full scrolled up. And has no problem with other web pages.

Comment: Have you tried to play with zoom in the window? Using Cmd + + and Cmd + -.